# Comment Control and Chat Rooms Request

Tags: feature-request

### I hope for functionality modifications to occur to the stack exchange network.

Discussions do develop within the comments section. At one time an option was given to me to move the discussion to a chat room. This option is not always given to me.

On topics that are in conflict to standard ideology even a few responses from five or so members can make for a sizable discussion.

Because of the size of the conversations that sometimes take place. I feel it adds pressure to the moderators to attempt to keep the site in some acceptable proportion. In effort to fix this the moderators have removed sections of conversation. Just to be clear: This is not a complaint against the moderators.

Instead I'm hoping to make their life easier. I notice that when I am given the option to move the conversation to a chat room, often this occurs after a large portion of a conversation has already occurred.

So what I am really hoping for is some extra user-side chat-room controls.

### Here are the examples:

**Instead of:**
Bob: Stuff
Fred: Stuff
Alf: conversation starter
Randy: response
Alf: response
Randy: response
Alf: response
Randy: response
Alf would you like to start a chat-room?

**Something like this:**
Bob: Stuff
Fred: Stuff
Alf: conversation starter         ^(Mouse pointer) Start Chat-room Here Button
Randy: response
Alf: response
Randy: response
Alf: response
Randy: response

**Resulting something like this:**
Bob: Stuff
Fred: Stuff
Alf and Randy Entered into Conversation, Care to Join?

**As members add into the chat:**
Alf, Randy, and 6 Others Entered into Conversation, Care to Join?

**If someone did not want to enter into their conversation:**
Bob: Stuff
Fred: Stuff
Alf, Randy, and 6 Others Entered into Conversation, Care to Join?
Paco: Stuff

Comment: This is a pretty good idea.

Comment: I like it a lot. But can Christianity mods do anything about it? Would it be better to ask on http://meta.stackexchange.com?